# In SQL Server 2014 Is it normal for for maintenance job to pick up a table that does not exist in database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, maintenance-plans

As above, we are hitting an error on the maintenance plan running on SQL Server 2014.

During update statistics when we got the error.

> "Msg 2706, Level 16, State 6 , Line 1" Table Flow Detail does not exist".

And when we searched against the database, the table does not exists.

What could be the reason?

I just reviewed it and realized it is failing for some weeks now. I just took over the administration, what can we do?

The following queries both return no rows:

```
select * from sys.objects where type = 'U' and name 'Flow Detail'

SELECT  ss.name as SchemaName, so.name as ObjectName
FROM    sys.objects so
   join sys.schemas ss on so.schema_id = ss.schema_id
where type = 'U' and so.name = 'FlowDetail'
```

Last ran checkdb on this database previous week but that checkdb passed successfully.

Unfortunately I am unable to run Ola Hallengren's maintenance scripts as it is is my customer db server.

Comment: Has this been reoccurring? Is there any chance the table existed, but was dropped at some point? Does the customer have rights to create/drop tables themselves?

Comment: @lowlydba The job has being failing since start of May as I reviewed the job history but why as much but why the maintenance job did not refresh its catalog?